# What is the right way to choose an EGL config in Android?

Tags: android, opengl-es, egl

I'm using my own GLSurfaceView and have been struggling with crashes related to the EGL config chooser for a while.

It seems as though requesting RGB_565 by calling `setEGLConfigChooser(5, 6, 5, 0, 16, 0)` should be the most supported. However, running this code on the emulator using host GPU I still get a crash, seemingly because my graphics card does not natively support RGB_565. Setting to RGBA_8888 by calling `setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 0)` seems to run fine on my emulator and HTC Rezound device, but I'm seeing a small number of crash reports in the market still.

My guess is that most phones support RGBA_8888 natively now but a small number of my users have phones which are only compatible with RGB_565, which prevents my config chooser from getting a config.

Seeing as how I don't need the alpha channel, is there a right way to try RGBA_8888 first and then fall back to RGB_565? Is there a cleaner way to just ask for any ol' config without caring about the alpha value?

I saw a possible solution to determine ahead of time what the default display config was and request that specifically here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20918779/234256. Unfortunately, it looks like the suggested getPixelFormat function is deprecated as of API level 17.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience I do not think setEGLConfigChooser() actually works correctly, i.e. it has a bug in its implementation. Across a number of devices I have seen crashes where setEGLConfigChooser() fails to select a valid context even if the underlying surface is of the correct type.

I have found the only reliable way to choose an EGL context is with a custom EGLConfigChooser. This also has the added benefit of choosing a config based on your own rules, e.g. surface *must* have depth and preferably RGB888 but can settle for RGB565. This is actually pretty straightforward to use [eglChooseConfig()](https://www.khronos.org/registry/egl/sdk/docs/man/html/eglChooseConfig.xhtml) to get a list of possible configurations and then return one of them that matches your selection criteria.

Comment: This looks promising. I will have to experiment with this and update this question with the results. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This gsoc code sample is for enabling MSAA. But it also contains code to select configurations, checking if they are available.

https://code.google.com/p/gdc2011-android-opengl/source/browse/trunk/src/com/example/gdc11/MultisampleConfigChooser.java#90